# validation start/end date messages with native html 5 tooltips

Tags: html, date, validation, momentjs, tooltip

what i´m trying to do is showing the typical date validation messages like "end date must be greater than start date" with the native html 5 tooltips, but i´m not able to find any example.

Any idea will be appreciated.
Thanks a lot!!

Comment: what have you tried or where are you stuck? You need to be more specific in your question so we can help.

Comment: Yes sorry. What i mean, i need to replicate the tooltips that appeared when an input is required and you don´t fill it,  but with a "custom" message. In this case, if you have chosen a previous date (like yesterday or a past day ) for end date a tooltip with something like"end date must be greater than start date".

Comment: The main problem aret html 5 native tooltips. how do i trigger them via jQuery?

Comment: I would suggest building something custom for that, although, adding/editing the `title` attribute may be able to help create something close to what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I know how to dinamically set an attribute like "data-original-title" to add the text i want to show. but how can i manage to trigger the tooltips/bubbles of html  with that info?

Comment: Finally i find a solution. setCustomValidity will do the job. Here is a good example:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oeaqWY
Thanks whodeee for the advice!!